# 'with the profession' or 'in the profession'

Tags: grammar

I have two questions.

1. Should I use 'with the profession' or 'in the profession' in this text?
2. Is this sentence gramatically correct?

Completed his education at the company-affiliated Basic Vocational School for working people WZE in Berlin **with the profession** of turner.

WZE - name of school

Comment: I can't see anywhere that 'challenges' or 'challenge' would be used in that sentence. Have you missed something out?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is mystifying, so I will address your second one and see if you edit to clarify.

The second sentence could do with some punctuation for clarity. A better phrase than 'with the profession' would be 'qualifying as'. So:

> Completed his education at the company-affiliated Basic Vocational School for working people, WZE, in Berlin, **qualifying as a professional** turner.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> Completed his education **as a turner** at the company-affiliated Basic Vocational School for working people, WZE, in Berlin.

This keeps the education and profession in the same thought, rather than tack it on at the end.
You can say *professional turner* if its more appropriate.